# Clicking drop down with Selenium WebDriver does not activate Javascript to add or remove items from the page.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I click an item in a drop down it doesn't activate the javascript on a given page.

Here is the element I am interacting with

```
<select id="DocumentComment_document_id" name="DocumentComment[document_id]">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Document 1</option>
<option value="2">Document 2</option>
</select>
```

Here is the Javascript that actually does the work

```
jQuery(function($) {
$("#DocumentComment_document_id").live("change", function(){
$.post(
"/wg/wg2/documentComment/ajaxLoadDelineators",
{"docID": $(this).val(),"ajax":true},
function(data){
$("#delineator_options").html(data);
}
);
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but you can define a "mouse action" with the Action class that will physically move the point pointer and click.  I would bet that would work where it wasn't working using the JavascriptExecutor.

Really, I don't see how you could go wrong here because you seem to see the entire option element contents which means that WebDriver should have no problem getting one of the 2 option elements and clicking it the standard way.

Answer (score 0):

A browser independent way to select an option from a traditional dropdown is just to click the option, without clicking the select first. It goes against the norm for Selenium, but it works

C# code (to select Document 1):

```
IWebElement theOption = _webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='DocumentComment_document_id']/option[@value='1']"));
theOption.Click();
```